# replacing a '"' character in a Python string

Tags: python, replace

I'm replacing several characters in a string. Some are alphabetic and work exactly as intended. But I also need to replace a double quotation mark and this fails.

```
    str = 'this contains the " character'
    for r in (('"', 'quo'),('c', 'CC'), ('t', 'TT')):
        result = str.replace(*r)
    print(result)  # the " doesn't get replaced
```

I tried using `'\"'` rather than `'"'` but that makes no difference. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your first one doesn't work fine. The `c` is not replaced with `CC` in `result`, because you aren't using the result of the previous replacement as the starting point for the next replacement.

Comment: By the way, it's a bad practice to overwrite Python's built-in `str` function by creating a variable named `str`

Comment: Hm. You are correct. What is the best way to do multiple replacements?

Comment: `print('this contains the " character'.replace('"'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are performing each replacement on the *original* string, not the result of each previous replacement. You need something like

```
s = 'this contains the " character'
result = s
for r in (('c', 'CC'), ('t', 'TT')):
    result = result.replace(*r)
print(result)  # works just fine
```